# Singleton class, private variable or method parameter. Performance

Tags: java, performance

I got 3 classes, A,B and C.

Only 1 instance of class A exits at any given time but hundreds of objects of class B and C will exist.

Class A calls a method of class B. 
Class B calls a method of class C.
And class C eventually calls a method of the class A object.

What would be the best and cleanest way to provide the reference to the class A object in C?

1. Saving it in a private variable and initializing it via the constructor?
2. Creating a static getInstance() method in Class A which returns the object itself?
3. Or passing "this" through parameters from A to B to C?

Any C Object will call the method of A multiple time in his lifetime.

Comment: (Before this post gets closed) #2

Comment: #2 is probably the slowest.

Comment: Second would be the cleanest.

Comment: It's not clear with #1 means.

Comment: Use an enum: `public enum EasySingleton{ INSTANCE; }`

Comment: @HotLicks #1: I mean that during the creation of object's of type B or C I could pass the object of class A as a reference and save it in a private variable in every object of B or C

Comment: That's probably the best choice, if you're reasonably sure that part of the design won't change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most convenient way is certainly #2. The "cleanest" is probably #1, or #3, depending on the circumstances.

The Singleton (#2) pattern has some problems. That does not mean you should avoid it at all costs. But you should be aware of the implications.

For some information on the topic see [What is so bad about singletons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons)

Comment: Thanks I will use this approach being aware of the limitations and the problems.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest create a static getInstance() method in Class A which returns the object itself.

Answer (score 0):

Option 2. Have your Singleton class contain the instance privately with a private constructor and return the instance using get instance. This the commonly used pattern.

Option 1 makes the constructor open to other methods which is not needed since it should only be called once (if I'm reading the option correctly). Option 3 will clutter your code.